# Can i open website from iOS app using UIWebview?

Tags: ios, xcode

My iOS application is related to a web product. I want to open website through UIWebView. Can i open that site from app? Will apple reject if i shows other sites.

Comment: If it's related to your app and content is ok, I don't see any reason for apple to reject it.

Comment: Yes you can open website using UIWebview without any problem. as per the documentation "You use the UIWebView class to embed web content in your application"